# How to integrate JMH when method parameter is an interface?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I need to `Benchmark` a method which parameter is an interface. When I use State annotation to that interface, it says `The State annotation does not support abstract classes.`

```
@Benchmark
public void doSomething(Migratable m) {
............
Update DB
............
}
```

Here, `Migratable` is an interface. 
Now, how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Migratable parameter a field of your benchmark class, initialize it in a @Setup method.